# How to stop autorevert polling

Tags: auto-revert-mode

To quote,

> By default, Auto-Revert mode works using file notifications, whereby
>   changes in the filesystem are reported to Emacs by the OS. You can
>   disable use of file notifications by customizing the variable
>   auto-revert-use-notify to a nil value, then Emacs will check for file
>   changes by polling every five seconds. You can change the polling
>   interval through the variable auto-revert-interval.

Even `auto-revert-use-notify` is t, auto revert still polls for every 5 seconds.  I want to disable such a polling because it results a block every time it polls. The block is due to the files are on a fuse mounted disk (via vmware).

Comment: Mounted filesystems cannot be watched by file notification. Likely, this is the reason autorevert continues to poll.

Comment: Is switching off `auto-revert-mode` an option? If not, you should mention that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

See https://debbugs.gnu.org/35418 - it discusses the problem.

Comment: This is an interesting discussion, thanks for the link. I was just wondering why `auto-revert-avoid-polling` isn't set to `nil` by default, and apparently that's the theme of the discussion. But please, could you provide a short summary of the discussion inside your answer? Otherwise it falls into "link-only" category, and [is a subject to being removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/2388257).

Answer (score 2):

You can just set `auto-revert-interval` to a very large value (like `most-positive-fixnum`).

Comment: interesting workaround.

Comment: the problem seems more involved because inotify is disabled until the next call of auto-revert-buffers, which is due to auto-revert-buffers-counter-lockedout